# how to include html menu page in another html page and how to highlight selected menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

here i created menu list in sepatare page name is menu.html

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="company.html">COMPANY</a>
    </li>
    <li ><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>

    </li>
    <li ><a href="aboutus.html">ABOUT US</a>

    </li>
    <li ><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i included menu.html page in aboutus.html and company.html pages as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).("click", "#cssmenu li a", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

$(this).addClass('active');

});
 </script>
<script>
  $(function(){


$("#menu").load("menu.html");
   });
   </script>
  <style>
   .active {
    color: #D09d23;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
 </style>

  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="menu">
  </div>
  Welcome to About Us
  </body>
    </html>
```

but the selected menu not highlighting.this is pure html and jquery.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `syntax` is wrong just try,

```
$(document).on("click", "#cssmenu li a", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

And initially set the `active class` to the element, which is going to display at beginning.

Comment: i used this one. menus are highlighting but pages not loading(not navigating to another link)

Comment: @user3030105 That is because you are preventing its default action.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a way to set active class to specific anchor tag on document ready:

```
var currentPage = window.location.pathname; //depending current page or set title tag for each page and use it
$(function () {
    $("#menu").load("menu.html",function(){
        $(this).find('a[href="'+currentPage+'"]').addClass('active');
    });
 });
```

Comment: i used this one. menus are not highlighting

Comment: check `window.location.pathname` should be e.g `aboutus.html` for the aboutus page, is it expected result? More accurate way would be to set a title tag for each page. And you could wish to set active class to the LI, not the anchor tag. Please consider to tell me what is not working. Class not added, error in console, etc...